# "Reflecting" on an XML document with an XML Schema in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

I have a `System.XML.Schema.XmlSchema` loaded into memory and an XML instance data of element types defined in the `XmlSchema`.

I have appInfo annotations defined in the schema that is each of type `MyFieldAppInfo` and I need to process through the XML elements and reflect the schema type definition and load the appInfo annotation for that element.

The XML data element could be loaded as a XmlDocument, a XmlElement, an XDocument, an XElement, or whatever built-in type would be best for performing this analysis.

The schemas are not known at design time.  But at runtime, the XML data will be a single item of a registered schema type. Visiting the nodes in the XML is easy, but then jumping to the corresponding element in the schema definition to grab its appInfo annotation is what I can't see the way to.

Any ideas how this might be achieved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this a different way and got an answer thanks to Xan.

[Find an annotation for an xml element in its associated schema-defined type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363115/find-an-annotation-for-an-xml-element-in-its-associated-schema-defined-type)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly you're trying to create and load arbitrary objects from xml given a schema description?

You'll need a recursive function to visit all the nodes of the input xml document.

Since xml nodes contain text you're going to have to determine the expected data type from the schema, do a conversion, and if it succeeds assume it's correct.

It doesn't seem tricky, am I missing something?

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks for taking the time to read and respond.  The xml data will be of a known type and there will be only one of them per "file".  Visiting the nodes is easy, but then jumping to the corresponding element in the schema to grab its appInfo annotation is what I can't see the way to.  Does that make sense?